# 'Struct' in pure C

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I'm working on a little project in pure C. I use gcc compiler (and thats the idea).
I have a struct as follows:

```
struct STACK{
  char var;
  struct STACK* next;
  struct STACK* prev;
};
```

and little lower in my function f():

```
STACK head;
head->var='a';
printf("%c", head->var);
```

Now, during compilation I get the error:

```
: In function ‘f’:
:13:3: error: unknown type name ‘STACK’
:14:7: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
:15:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong ? When I was working in C++ and g++ everything seemed fine.

=================
EDIT:

OK, that worked, but now I have to dynamically create structures of type STRUCT and only keep pionters to them. Is it possible in C ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `struct` keyword before the struct name `STACK`:

```
struct STACK head;
```

instead of:

```
STACK head;
```

---

Also you are using `->` which is usually applied to pointers. Just use the `.` instead:

```
head.var
```

Remember that:

```
x->y
```

can be translated to:

```
(*x).y
```

---

Finally if you define a struct as:

```
typedef struct {
    char var;
    struct STACK* next;
    struct STACK* prev;
} STACK;
```

you can declare the variable as:

```
STACK head;
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition is okay, but to declare a variable, try:

```
struct STACK head;
```

And to refer to it's members,

```
head.var = 'a';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Can you please tell me why arrow notation does not ?

Comment: The arrow is used when head contains a pointer to a structure.  When the variable is the struct itself, we refer to the members with dot.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided a typedef for your struct you need to declare as

```
struct STACK head;
```

also `head` is not a pointer so the use of `->` should be replaced with `.` when you accees its members